# localstorage of config works locally, but not through server

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I have an app that consists of three main pages. Each of the pages communicates to a server using a URL, a user, and a password. These three items are entered on a jquery mobile config popup from one of the three main screens.

I was concerned about the fact that configuration from page 1 would not be accessible from page 2, but when I ran locally using flat files, it worked fine, so I chalked it up to that all the storage was owned by the config dialog and went on my way.

Now, when I deploy to a server, it looks as if the config is never getting stored, as it keeps going back and requesting the config dialog again from the user.

I have found that if I go to the config page directly, change the values, and save them, the values get saved just fine. The issue is when I use it as a popup.

I am new to javascript and don't know where to go next. I guess I could change it from being a popup to a full page and that might fix the issue, but would like it to work as a popup for improved flow.

Comment: Are the pages on the same origin? (domain/subdomain). Locally run files will all be of the same origin; _localhost_.

Comment: @PaulS. Yes. Everything except the page itself, like index.html, seat.html

Comment: Next step: Open your developer console with your browser on the pages and check for error messages and for the items in the `localStorage` _Object_ on both pages.

Comment: @PaulS. Added new information uncovered. No errors.

Comment: without seeing some code it's hard to guess, but accessing localstorage is asynchronous, so I hope you are running all your logic depending in a callback.